# EFCore OrderBy not ordering correctly by date field

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a list of 146 items in a database table that has a date field.  In the table they're in no particular order, thanks to EF's inability (deliberately, from what I understand) to guarantee order in a bulk insert.  So I'm pulling everything out using the following:

```
// Records is a complex object consisting of a bunch of doubles, an integer ID, and a date
// Date is a DateTime, but with a time component of midnight.
var rawData = await Task.Run(() =>_context.Records.OrderBy(item => item.Date).ToList());
```

The weird thing is what happens when I look in the Autos window.  Here are the dates of the last 12 items:

> 7/31/2020
> 8/1/2020
> 8/2/2020
> 8/3/2020
> 8/4/2020
> 8/5/2020
> 8/6/2020
> 8/7/2020
> 8/8/2020
> 8/11/2020
> 8/10/2020
> 8/9/2020

That's... not fully sorted, though it *is* the order in which I entered the data.

Interestingly, the list does show signs of being sorted.  The table (in SQLite) uses an identity column, and here are the IDs of those same 5 items in the same order as they appear in the Auto window:

> 52
> 46
> 47
> 48
> 49
> 50
> 51
> 71
> 143
> 144
> 145
> 146

As you can see, it looks semi-sorted, for lack of better phrasing.  Specifically, the first 9 data points I'm showing (and really all of them up to that point) were sorted correctly.  Then I added a data point (8/11), re-requested the data, and it looked fine.  Then I added the next data point (8/10), re-requested the data, and now both points I added are unsorted.  Same with the next one (8/9).

The difference between the first 143 data points and the last three is that the first ones were already in the SQLite file.  The last three were added to test the add/edit functionality on my app, so they were created in the app and written to the file during my debug session.

I'm at a loss here.  Am I missing something here?  Could my `await` be screwing things up?  Or do I need to use `AsNoTracking` just to make my data sort somehow?

Comment: SQLite does not have a datetime data type, most likely you are using Text. If you are converting to DateTime, you can sort it after the query is executed.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
var rawData = await context.Records.OrderBy(item => item.Date).ToListAsync();
```

How your context is initialized ?

you can try

```
using (var context = serviceProvider.GetService<RecordsContext>())
{
  var rawData = await context.Records.OrderBy(item => item.Date).ToListAsync();
}
```

or

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly RecordsContext _context;

    public MyController(RecordsContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<List<Record>> GetRecords()
    {
      return await _context.Records.OrderBy(item => item.Date).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: No dice.  The `ToListAsync()` didn't fix it.  Thanks though!  (And I'm using DI to get my context, per your second example.)